# Error while trying to read from file C

Tags: file, input

I have a file and i need to read data from it. I have to read 2 int and 1 c string.
This is my struct

```
typedef struct seats
{
int number, reserved;
char * name;
} seats;
```

This is my main

```
FILE *data;
seats input;
data = fopen("data.txt", "r+");
while(fscanf(data,"%s %d %d", input.name, &input.number, &input.reserved) != EOF)
{
    printf("%s %d %d", input.name, input.number, input.reserved);
}
```

Every time when i compile and run this software it crashes for some reason. Is there any solution?

Comment: What format is the data in? Is it text? Is it binary? Little-endian? Big-endian?

Comment: Does the tool you are using provide any sort of Logging system? If so, edit your question, and add relevant information such as the Tool, the language, the libraries used, etc. Otherwise we can only guess based on common mistakes.  Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Its not login system, its simple assigment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your struct to something like this:

```
typedef struct seats{
    int number, reserved;
    char name[1000];
} seats;
```

and put a fflush(stdin), after printf(...)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned any value to `input.name`, but you pass its garbage value to `fscanf`. You need to assign a variable a value before you attempt to use that value.

Comment: when i added `input.name="text"` before i used it in fscanf it crashed also.

Comment: @NikolaButigan String literals are in read-only memory area (in modern OSes, with default compiler options), so setting input.name to point to string literal and then asking scanf to overwrite it will indeed cause segmentation fault.

Comment: @NikolaButigan Well that's even worse. Now you're passing `fscanf` a pointer to a constant and asking it to modify what that pointer points to.